# MockEndpoint fails to run route

Tags: java, apache-camel

Using [mock](http://camel.apache.org/mock.html) to launch a salesforce streaming route as shown [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-salesforce/camel-salesforce-component/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/salesforce/StreamingApiIntegrationTest.java) fails for the following route:

```
from("salesforce:AccountUpdateTopic?notifyForFields=ALL&notifyForOperations=ALL")  
.tracing().convertBodyTo(String.class).to("file:D:/tmp/")
.to("mock:output") 
.log("SObject ID: ${body}");
```

in

```
package org.apache.camel.component.salesforce;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.OperationName;
import org.junit.Test;

public class StreamingApiIntegrationTest extends AbstractSalesforceTestBase {

    @Test
    public void testSubscribeAndReceive() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:AccountUpdateTopic");
        mock.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        mock.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder doCreateRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // test topic subscription
                from("salesforce:AccountUpdateTopic?notifyForFields=ALL&notifyForOperations=ALL").tracing().convertBodyTo(String.class).to("file:D:/tmp/").to("mock:output").log("SObject ID: ${body}");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Running this test does not start the route (updates are not fetched from Salesforce and stored in /tmp/).

Can mock run a route and wait for updates from Salesforce? Is there a shorter example that allows for testing salesforce routes without making use of spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the [Camel Mock](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/mock-component.adoc) component. Mocks are not starting anything. They are just endpoints who record and assert the messages they receive.

To trigger a Camel route you have to send a message to it. You can do this easily using a [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html).

It is this line from the example you mention that does exactly that.

```
CreateSObjectResult result = template().requestBody(
        "direct:upsertSObject", merchandise, CreateSObjectResult.class);
```

`template` is the [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) and `requestBody` the method to send a message to the endpoint `direct:upsertSObject` and wait for a response. See the [Javadocs of ProducerTemplate](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html) for the various existing signatures.